# PYSPARK: What is the optimization technique used in pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression

What is the optimization technique used in pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression? Is it gradient decent or gradient ascent or something else? If it is one the gradient algorithm how can I specify the stepSize? 
I do not see any stepSize parameter in the Logistic regression class:

```
class pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression(self, featuresCol="features", labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", maxIter=100, regParam=0.0, elasticNetParam=0.0, tol=1e-6, fitIntercept=True, threshold=0.5, thresholds=None, probabilityCol="probability", rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction", standardization=True, weightCol=None, aggregationDepth=2, family="auto")
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs the `fit` method takes additional params, but going down the rabbit hole to try and find where `fit` actually points is quite difficult. That being said if you take a look at the [`mllib.classification` module](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) you will find that the first implementation of Logistic Regression is [`LogisticRegressionWithSGD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD). There you will find a deprecation note pointing you to the `ml.classifcation` module.

> **Note**: Deprecated in 2.0.0. Use ml.classification.LogisticRegression or LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.

So in essence spark is telling you that if you want to use SGD then use `ml.classifcation.LogisticRegression`. My assumption (currently untested) would be that you could use the parameters for the `mllib.classifcation.LogisticRegressionWithSGD` method as the `params=` kwargs for the `ml.classification.LogisticRegression.fit` method. So in this case you could try passing something like the folliwng. Note the default step for the old `mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train` method was 1.0.

```
my_lr_model = my_lr_obj.fit(params={'step': 0.5})
```

Comment: Thanks, I used it as you suggested. The problem is that when I change the step size, I do not see any changes in my result. I used step sizes 0.00001 to 10000. This may tell us ml.classification.LogisticRegression.fit is not considering the step size parameter.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. I tried similar with `step_size` and `stepSize` and got no changes as well. I have to imagine they are still using some form of gradient descent by default so there has to be some way of changing step size. This is going to bother me now.